# Where to store Cron Jobs, and will they always run?

Tags: cron, cpanel

I have thought of using cron jobs recently. In my site, I have `css`, `js` and `images` folders in my setup, which isn't very relevant, but might be needed.

I know how to do a cron job, but am unsure as to where to put it in my files so that it always runs every day.

So where should I put the cron job file, should I create a new folder for it and what should the file extension be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log in to your system via SSH, and then enter,

`crontab -e`

If this is your first time editing, it may ask you what editor you would like to use. 
Then start editing.

`*/1 * * * * /var/www/mysite/public/cron/script.php`

Will run script.php every minute.

Comment: Cpanel has it's own cron interface.

Comment: Sorry, you should of mentioned that you needed to see how to do it in cpanel. You should just check cpanel faqs. It should be blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 4):

The cron I have installed on my Mythbuntu system keeps its daily cron scripts in `/etc/cron.daily/`.

File extensions don't matter on *nix. The file just needs to have executable permissions (and should have a shebang line at the top to state what program it should be run with).

Comment: And will this **always** run? And what file extension should I use?

Comment: Read the answer! "File extensions don't matter", so use any (or none) extension you like.

Answer (score 3):

anywhere, but I recommend outside web root. file extension to match the file type

Answer (score 2):

Does not matter where you put it, as long as you call all included files by their absolute paths to avoid confusion. I've run into situations where

```
include '../../start.php';
```

had issues when running using the php command (usr/bin/php I think it was). Probably because it was running it from the different folder under which the php running command lies on the Apache server. So when including files I would use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] as a reference point to include files.

alternatively you can always use the wget command to run it as if you are running it out of your own browser. Here's what I use:

wget http://www.mydomain.ca/cron/cron_whatever.php

And the timing can be set using the cPanel cron option, or you can write it out too. 
And always have email notifications turned on to make sure you get the results written out to see if there's any issues.

Comment: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm   shows you the WGET options.

Answer (score 1):

You don't edit cron directly but rather run `crontab -e` which will effectively save allow you to edit and save it into a system area.

Comment: i assume he means the files\apps he calls with a cron job. but then again maybe you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH as described by guys before, but there is some hosting service providers who use cPanel and allows you to create those cron jobs easily via a web based interface easy to use and you will also easily make the correct time for run with them .